# How to Embed Jquery Timepicker

Tags: jquery, embed, timepicker

I'm trying to figure out how to embed a time picker, in this case I'm using the jquery timepicker from Jon Thornton.
Turning the input class into a div or span hides the whole thing.
Users should see the embedded time picker as soon as they select the parenting tab.
The selected time, should then remain highlighted.

My Current code:

```
$('#time').click(function(){
    $('.setTime').timepicker();
});

<div class="tab-pane" id="time">
    <p>What time is it happening</p>
    <span class="setTime"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: likely need to set option for it to be open and date/time pickers usually work on `input` elements unless you tell the api where to put selected values withing options config

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! However I do not want an input field visible. I will look into the options, thanks